# Problem creating a custom category page with pagination

Tags: templates

I am creating a `category-{slug}.php` page for a specific category. This page has pagination also. This code successfully worked when calling the first page of the category page, but the problem starts when I clicked the pagination link.

When I clicked the "older entries" in the pagination, the URL changed to the following, but it's loading with `index.php` instead of `category-{slug}.php` and unable to show the post list:

```
http://localhost:90/wordpress/category/news/page/2/
```

The following URL is loading the `category-news.php` successfully:

```
http://localhost:90/wordpress/category/news/page/1/
```

My code of the page `category-news.php` is as follows...

```
get_header();
wp_reset_query(); ?>   
<div class="pagewrap post-page-article">
    <?php $count = 0;

    //Added
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    global $query_string;
    query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged );
    //--End of addition

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $this_page_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full', false );
        $this_page_img = $this_page_img[0];
        $this_page_title = get_the_short_title();
        $this_page_brief = get_the_short_excerpt( 200 );
        $this_page_url = get_the_permalink();
        ?><div class="wide-colum-3">
            <div class="image-side-block">
                <img src="<?php echo $this_page_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this_page_title; ?>">
            </div>
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $this_page_url; ?>"><?php echo $this_page_title; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $this_page_brief; ?></p>
            <div class="clear-fix"></div>
            <hr class="green-bar">
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;

    // next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>    
    <div class="clear-fix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Don't use query_posts, it can cause problems with pagination. Try WP_Query or get_posts instead.

Comment: @Gabriel just use the default loop. There is no need for a custom query at all

Comment: @PieterGoosen I need this category page to show only 2 posts of "news" category. How could this be possible with default loop? please post some code example.

Comment: @Gabriel I changed my code and used wp_query . But the problem still exist. 1st page load perfectly but when going to page 2 it's neither loading the custom template nor showing any post. Please help with some code.

Comment: See my answer. It should do the trick ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On request, a custom template does not mean custom query :-).

As already mentioned, **NEVER** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object and page functionality, one of which is pagination. Many plugins and functions relies on the main query object, you break that, you break those functions as well.

As this is a custom category template, it is also not necessary to run a custom query at all to get the thinks done that you want done. The main query can be **safely** altered with `pre_get_posts` for a specified template before the main query executes in order to get your desired result.

You can do the following in your `functions.php`, this will give you 2 posts per page on your custom category template **and** it will correctly handle your pagination issue ;-)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only targets front end
         && $q->is_main_query() // Targets only the main query
         && $q->is_category( 'SPECIAL CATEGORY' ) // Only targets your custom category page, change accordingly
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 ); // Sets 2 posts per page on special category page
    }
});
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out. Enjoy :-)